# HTML 5 upload file can't save

Tags: jquery, html, upload

I'm trying to upload file via FormData and XMLHttpRequest, file cannot save into folder i don't know where i wrong.
Finally i hope can send this message because i get this: Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.

upload.php

```
<?
$target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['filetext']['name']);
$exten = basename( $_FILES['filetext']['name']);
$exten = substr($exten, -4);
if($exten == ".png" || $exten == ".jpg" || $exten == ".bmp" || $exten == ".gif")
{
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filetext']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
 {
  echo $_FILES['filetext']['name']."\n". $test;
 }
 else
 {
  echo 0;
 }
}
else
{
 echo 0;
}?>
```

upload.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 function defaults(e){
   e.stopPropagation();  
   e.preventDefault();  
 }
 $(":file").live("change", function(){
    handleFiles(this.files);
});
 function handleFiles(files,e){
    // Traverse throught all files and check if uploaded file type is image 
    var imageType = /image.*/;  
    var file = files[0];
    // check file type
    if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {  
      alert("File \""+file.name+"\" is not a valid image file, Are you trying to screw me :( :( ");
      return false; 
    } 
    // check file size
    if (parseInt(file.size / 1024) > 2050) {  
      alert("File \""+file.name+"\" is too big. I am using shared server :P");
      return false; 
    } 

    var info = '<div class="preview active-win"><div class="preview-image"><img ></div><div class="progress-holder"><span id="progress"></span></div><span class="percents"></span><div style="float:left;">Uploaded <span class="up-done"></span> KB of '+parseInt(file.size / 1024)+' KB</div>';

    $(".upload-progress").show("fast",function(){
        $(".upload-progress").html(info); 
        uploadFile(file);
    });
    }
      function uploadFile(file){
      var fd = new FormData();
      fd.append('filez', file);
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
    xhr.open("POST", "upload.php", true);
    xhr.send(fd);

    function uploadProgress(event) {
if (event.lengthComputable) {
        $("#progress").css("width",(event.loaded / event.total) * 100 + "%");
        $(".percents").html(" "+((event.loaded / event.total) * 100).toFixed() + "%");
        $(".up-done").html((parseInt(event.loaded / 1024)).toFixed(0));
    } else {
        alert("Failed to compute file upload length");
    }
           }
     function uploadComplete(event) {
$("#progress").css("width","100%");
    $(".percents").html("100%");
    $(".up-done").html((parseInt(file.size / 1024)).toFixed(0));
     }
     function uploadFailed(event) {
     alert("There was an error attempting to upload the file.");
     }
     function uploadCanceled(event) {
       alert("The upload has been canceled by the user or the browser dropped the   connection.");
      }
       }

      });
```

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="file" name="filez" accept="image/*"> 
<div class="upload-progress"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Solved bad name: $_FILES['filetext']

Comment: Answer your own question and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little bit messy.

Since you are using jQuery, take a look at the end of this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Cheers.